# Twitter stuck on an endless redirect loop due to the new GDPR pop up (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, twitter

About a week ago Twitter would no longer let me log in on their site due to a popup which caused an infinite redirect loop. I have tried Mobile mode and TweetDeck so far but none of these worked for me, is there anything else I could try?

Edit 1: I have now tried Twitter on my phone and on a few other browsers but all of them have the same problem.

Comment: Try Incognito mode

Comment: @Appleoddity I have already tried Incognito mode and other browsers (Firefox,Opera) aswell. None seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried a browser that you surely have never used for twitter? Or tried to delete all cookies, local storage etc?  When this popup appeared first, have you accepted the new conditions? Just because they warned: if you decline, your account will be deleted (or disabled??) as far as I remember.

Comment: @deadcandidate I cant accept the new conditions because the pop-up won't even load and yes i have tried Firefox Chromium Chrome and Opera so far and none of them have worked and i never used Firefox or Opera.

Comment: @wechh
Something doesn't clean for me: now I've tried to open twitter.com from a clean browser and I haven't got that GDPR message... weird...

Comment: @deadcandidate Which browser did you use?

Comment: @wechh  a chromium on ubuntu linux. And now I tried a chrome on android, with the same result. Ooops... your mobile uses wifi or mobile network?

Comment: I Use WiFi/WLAN.

Comment: @wechh  could you try it via mobile net or an open access point or use a free proxy or anything else which helps you to keep off your ISP? I think this error caused by your  ISP or your router (assuming you have no own proxy)

Comment: just tried using an VPN and its still the same error.

Comment: When you say you tried from your phone, you meant browser or app?

Comment: @arieljannai app.

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of what error you are seeing on browser?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Chrome.

Try to press cancel button (near to address bar) when page is loading. Now, you can accept new GDPR rules by pressing button in right top corner.

I had the same problem and this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue. Tried incognito, proxy, app, all available browsers on mobile and pc. Contacting support, changing password and all to no avail.
Answer is simple, create a new account. Nothing seems to work...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I have the same issue too and can't access Twitter for many months... Hope creating a new account will help...